# C++ Template, Functions define in a class?

Tags: c++, templates, struct

Class.h

```
template<class T>
  struct AStruct
  {
     //stuff
  };

class aClass
{
  template<class T>
  void setStruct(const AStruct<T>& s)
  {
    theStruct = s; 
  }

private:
  template<class T>
  AStruct<T> theStruct;  //this is not liked.  "multiple template parameter lists are not allowed" are one of the errors I get... 
};
```

Quite the mess but still, I'd like to know what can be done about it... I've tried playing around a bit but with no luck... Also, only standard library please!

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: How will the Constructor make theStruct if it does not know what T is? You need to template the entire class if you have a variable that requires a template.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I was hoping there would be another way... :(

Comment: There's no language (or standard library) support for changing a variable's type at runtime as this code tries to do; but a dynamic type library like [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html) might be useful for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are holding a member that is a class template, then you either need a class template, or you need to provide a type for the template parameter. It seems like you need the former:

```
template<class T>
class aClass
{
  void setStruct(const AStruct<T>& s){
   theStruct = s; 
  }

private:
  AStruct<T> theStruct; // data member is class template
};
```

Comment: Motivation for selecting this as the correct answer: Both you and Andre had same answer and seem to have answered even at the same time so for fairness's sake, this answer has been selected by throwing head or tails.

Answer (score 4):

```
template<class T>
struct AStruct{
};

template<class T>         //<-- the template must be here
class aClass {
public:
    void setStruct(const AStruct<T>& s){
         theStruct = s; 
    }
private:
    AStruct<T> theStruct; //<-- To construct this variable
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `template<class T>`

```
template<class T>
struct AStruct{
 //stuff
};

template<class T>
class aClass{

 void setStruct(const AStruct<T>& s){
  theStruct = s; 
}

private:
AStruct<T> theStruct;   
};
```

You already defined `AStruct` to be a template

Comment: I don't actually have knowledge at compile time what T is though so if I remove it, it will say "identifier "T" is undefined",

Comment: But now you're trying to instantiate `AStruct` for a nonexistent type `T`. It either needs to be instantiated for an existing type, or `aClass` itself needs to be a template.